# Why is my Button still interactable even when condition is true?

Tags: unity, c#

When `BuyCloth()` is executed, Condition `itemIsBought` is `True`, but the Button is still interactable. Why is that?

```
private bool itemIsBought;

public static int coinAmount;

[SerializeField] private Button btn;


private void Start()
}
 StartCoroutine(CheckUnlockCoroutine());
}

    public void BuyCloth()
    {
        itemIsBought = true;
        Debug.Log("" + itemIsBought);
    }



    IEnumerator CheckUnlockCoroutine()
    {       

        while (itemIsBought == false)
        {

            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(.1f);

            
            
             if (coinAmount <= 100)
             {
                 btn.interactable = false;
             }
             else if (itemIsBought == true)
             {
                 btn.interactable = false;
                 
             }
            else
            {
                btn.interactable = true;
            }
        }
        

    }
```

I'm not sure what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
while (itemIsBought == false)
```

Exits the loop when you set it to true. I'd redo this with a few changes:

1. In BuyCloth() add

   ```
   btn.interactable = false;
   ```
2. Whenever coinAmount changes, call a SaleUpdate method that checks each item if you can afford it and set interactable to true or false there.
3. Create a public Ready(int currentCoins): set coinAmount, call SaleUpdate, then if already bough set interactable to false. Call this before gameObject.SetActive(true) on this script's GameObject.

   1. Or better, but requires a bit more knowledge: You have a ScriptableObject with int CurrentCoins; and in the Ready() function you grab that value for coinAmount. And in BuyCloth() you can subtract the coins from the CurrentCoins.
4. Delete this coroutine entirely.

Comment: _Exits the loop when you set it to true._ but presumably, the value becomes true during `yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(.1f);`, so it would get into the `else if (itemIsBought == true)`?

Comment: Maybe that will happen. I like my code to be more deterministic. It's a bunch more work to know what the resulting optimized IL and machine code are doing with "that code can run whenever".

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're making an idle game where the coins are trickling in every frame, running a loop to check every tenth of a second to see if the state has changed is extremely inefficient. If the player spends 10 seconds thinking about their next move before clicking, your code has run 100 times to check a coin count and purchase status that have not changed since the last check. Multiply this by a dozen buttons all checking for whether they should enable and you've got thousands of redundant method calls for no benefit.

This is the kind of situation where [the Observer Pattern](https://www.gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html) is a good fit. It lets your code say "This is the state I'm interested in - let me know when it changes", and then incur zero execution overhead until there's a relevant state change to react to.

Here's an example implementation. First, we separate out a script to handle our current coin inventory (because several other scripts might all care about that):

```cs
public class Wallet : MonoBehaviour {

    // Make editable in inspector, but not directly settable by other scripts.
    [field:SerializeField]
    public int CoinCount { get; private set; }

    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI _coinDisplay;

    // Expose event to notify observerse when coin count changes.
    public UnityEvent<int> onCoinCountChanged;

    // Any changes to wallet contents must go via this function
    // (passing a negative argument to subtract coins).
    public void AddCoins(int coinsAdded) {
        CoinCount += coinsAdded;
        HandleCoinCountChange();
    }

    void HandleCoinCountChange() {
        // Let everyone who cares about the coin count know the latest value.
        onCoinCountChanged?.Invoke(CoinCount);

        // Update the displayed counter.
        _coinDisplay.text = CoinCount.ToString();
    }

    // Also invoke events correctly if coin count is changed in inspector.
    int _cachedCount;
    void OnValidate() {
        if (CoinCount != _cachedCount) {
            _cachedCount = CoinCount;
            HandleCoinCountChange();
        }
    }
}
```

Then we make another script to put on any button that purchases an item. Note that this script makes no assumption that the item to be bought is "cloth" or that it must cost 100 - so you can re-use the same script for multiple purchasables at different prices.

```cs
// Put this script on the same object as the UI button to get
// automatic wiring-up of the reference and validation that
// the required button component is present (will create if absent).
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class PurchaseButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool IsPurchased { get; private set; }

    public bool CanPurchase => (!IsPurchased) && (_wallet.CoinCount >= _cost);

    // Use Inspector to select the Wallet script for this player.
    // (You could use a singleton here, but this supports multiple wallets
    // for e.g. multiplayer games)
    [SerializeField]
    Wallet _wallet;

    [SerializeField]
    int _cost = 100;

    Button _button;

    // Get the attached Button and wire up events automatically.
    // You could do this in the Inspector if you prefer, but this makes set-up
    // a little simpler, and has low overhead for just a dozen or so buttons.
    void Awake() {
        TryGetComponent(out _button);
        _button.onClick.AddListener(TryPurchase);
        _wallet.onCoinCountChanged.AddListener(UpdatePurchaseState);

        UpdatePurchaseState(_wallet.CoinCount);
    }

    void TryPurchase() {
        if (CanPurchase) {
            _wallet.AddCoins(-_cost);
            IsPurchased = true;
            _button.interactable = false;
        }
    }

    void UpdatePurchaseState(int coinCount) {
        _button.interactable = CanPurchase;
    }
}
```